# Python merge multiple if and for conditions

Tags: python

I am checking data from a dictionary and i need to extract different items:

host that are in a certain environment.

host that have a certain software lower than x.

I can loop over the dictionary items twice but I am not able to merge the two if conditions.

this is what a dict looks like:

```
host_data = {'dev8': {'sw': [{'software_id': 'xxxx', 'software_version': 'xx'}, {'software_id': 'yyyy', 'software_version': 'zzz'}], 'env': 'dev'}}
```

this is what i have so far but it does not do what i want only the 'else' is exectuted.

```
ENV = ['production', 'test']
for host,data in host_data.items():
     if data['env'] not in ENV:
        print (host, data['env'])
     else:
        for item in range(len(data['sw'])):
             if data['sw'][item]['software_id'] is None:
                print(host, data['sw'])
             elif data['sw'][item]['software_id'] == 'xxxxxxx':
                  if version_tuple(data['sw'][item]['software_version']) < (6,):
                      print (host, data['sw'][item]['software_version'])
```

is it possible to merge and only loop over dictionary items once so far i have two for loops going over `host_data.items()`

Comment: > only the `else` is executed.

Are you sure? Looks like only the `if` will evaluate true and print the host, env. It's not clear what you're end goal is. Can you provide what you want your sample output to look like?

Comment: I don't get the `else` part to execute because `data['env']` is `dev` and is not in `ENV`.

Comment: I just want to print the host and env if the host in not in prod, or test: like this: ` dev8  dev`
If the host in in ENV  then print the host and the software version if lower than 6:
`dev8 5.10`

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping over `dict` items twice, these are nested loops.
The first one `for host, data in host_data.items()` will only go over one single item (`dev8` and its corresponding `dict` value).
The other loop goes over `sw` inside that `dict`, this cannot be simplified.

However, the code in the loop can:

```py
host_data = {
    'dev8': {
        'sw': [{'software_id': 'xxxx', 'software_version': 'xx'},
               {'software_id': 'yyyy', 'software_version': 'zzz'}],
        'env': 'dev'}
}

ENV = ['production', 'test']

for host, data in host_data.items():
    if data['env'] not in ENV:
        print(host, data['env'])

    else:
        for sw_item in data['sw']:
            if sw_item['software_id'] is None: 
                print(host, data['sw'])

            elif sw_item['software_id'] == 'xxxxxxx' \
                    and version_tuple(sw_item['software_version']) < (6,):
                print(host, sw_item['software_version'])
```